# Typescript for "type, or function returning type"

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

It's useful to allow consumers to provide configuration either as static data, or as a function returning that same schema of data.

Consider some example types:

```
type T1 = { a: string } | (() => { a: string });
type T2 = { b: boolean, c: number } | (() => { b: boolean, c: number });
type T3 = string[] | (() => string[]);
```

In general, these types look like:

```
type T<V> = V | (() => V);
```

How can I write a type which takes some value in the form of `T<V>`, and returns `V`?

I tried:

```
type ResolveMaybeFunction<T> = ReturnType<T> | T;
```

But this is no good because `ReturnType<T>` results in `any`, so `ResolveMaybeFunction<T>` always results in `any`.

Overall, I want the following results:

```
ResolveMaybeFunction<string | (() => string)>                       === string;
ResolveMaybeFunction<{ a: number[] } | (() => { a: number[] })>     === { a: number[] };
ResolveMaybeFunction<AnyArbitraryType | (() => AnyArbitraryType)>   === AnyArbitraryType;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [Conditional Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to check if the given type
is a function, and then use the return type of the function if it is.

```
type ResolveMaybeFunction<T> = T extends ((...args: any) => any) ? ReturnType<T> : T
```

This says if `T` is of type function with any number of arguments and has a return value, use the return type of the function.
Otherwise, just use the original type

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA3lAhgLigZ2AJwEsA7AcygF8oAfKACjoEokA+VDbPIsyxgbgBQoSLABMSdgCNskgPayANhHTEANFADG2YgFcAtpIj5KNek1ZSZ8pSvVaoug0d6Dh0GAGYJXEqQDaALqmDMyIbD5kgfwCQuDQAEoQOIoAbhAAsugghgBiOsQawISyxAA8MGzIMFAQAB7AEMQAJjhmAHQd6PikONgqIKFs-cwA-FCJwDr4xDBx5WzYMLEiickKaZnZEHkFRSWi8xLVdQ3NrQwdbV09fcQDFiQAZs4AqqNQL1CLMW6wScAIZCrVIZLK5fKFYplCLkWghCwwxhsKAo1Fo9EYqACAD02NRAD0Rst3P9xECkiDNuDdlDSmgsA59IZ8IETHDzGF2AzHMzWRQkeicXiUYTiX88F5yWsNmDthC9sQDjDghzwgRfALMVrMUKCUTfjB-gAWCTA9agrY7SH7OkcRlOFlBKjswZc7RMox8zWo3UikZAA)

Comment: I think this is as succinct as it could get!

Answer (score 1):

You can just disregard the function member from the union type with `Exclude<MyUnion, MembersToExclude>`, since the value itself and the return value of the function type should be the same.

```
type Test1 = Exclude<'a' | 'b', 'b'> // 'a'
type Test1 = Exclude<'a' | () => 'a', () => unknown> // 'a'
```

Which in your case might look like this:

```
type MaybeFunction<V> = V | (() => V);

type ResolveMaybeFunction<T extends MaybeFunction<unknown>> =
  Exclude<T, () => unknown>

type Test1 = ResolveMaybeFunction<123 | () => 123> // 123
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAYgVwHYGNgEsD2GAPAGoB8UAvFCVAD5QAUjAlFRSSwNwBQPokKACUIAZ3wAbAG4R4SVJhwFiAFSgQAHsAgYAJqNgJk6bHkJFMAawz4A7hjIVKPKFACiGrBLS6IRFQA0TGyUFFY29mR80QLQKgCMVFAA3lBwAFxQosAATrgYAOZQAL70TKzsKWmZ2XmFJdz84HFiwInUIuLSskYKpsr+8VEA9MOuUAB6APx8sVAqAExJqYiZiPiSEHAYQViZGGgAtsg5JWXMIRQraxsSWztQe1AHxxCnxY1zKq1LHWKSMjkxkUZlUCxGY1c01mzXmAGYkrV8gUANoAXXOFVCWVyyPRn1h32yCL+XUBvRMSnMKjhEPG0yAA)

---

Note that if the value type itself is a function this won't work.

```
type T4 = MaybeFunction<() => 'a'>;
type Test4 = ResolveMaybeFunction<T4>
//   ^? never
```

Resolving that is more complicated. But maybe that's not a problem that needs solving.